# XSLT flat structure to hiearchical

Tags: xml, xslt, hierarchy

I have an existing xml file with data in the following format. The first three letters of code determine the same group.

```
    <Subjects>
        <subject>
        <code>ANT001000</code>
            <literal>ANTIQUES / Americana</literal>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <code>ANT002000</code>
            <literal>ANTIQUES / Art</literal>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <code>CKB100000</code>
            <literal>COOKING / Beverages / General</literal>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <code>CKB006000</code>
            <literal>COOKING / Beverages / Bartending</literal>
        </subject>
    </Subjects>
```

I need to transform it to look like this:

```
    <node name="Antiques" id="1">
        <node name="Americana" id="2" />
        <node name="Art" id="3" />
    </node>
<node name="Cooking" id="4">
        <node name="Beverages " id="6" />
            <node name="General" id="7" />
            <node name="Bartending" id="8" />
        </node>
</node>
```

I tried several approaches but couldn't get it work. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show at least one of those "several approaches". Thanks!

Comment: This is not going to be simple. Please indicate whether using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- Also is there any meaning to the rest of the code (which could perhaps be used to make this easier)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this in several passes:

The first pass would tokenize the categories listed in the `literal` element of each `subject` and create a `category` node for each. In the given example, this would result in:

```
  <category path="">ANTIQUES</category>
  <category path="ANTIQUES/">Americana</category>
  <category path="">ANTIQUES</category>
  <category path="ANTIQUES/">Art</category>
  <category path="">COOKING</category>
  <category path="COOKING/">Beverages</category>
  <category path="COOKING/Beverages/">General</category>
  <category path="">COOKING</category>
  <category path="COOKING/">Beverages</category>
  <category path="COOKING/Beverages/">Bartending</category>
```

The next step would select all top categories (i.e. categories with an empty @path attribute):

```
  <category path="">ANTIQUES</category>
  <category path="">ANTIQUES</category>
  <category path="">COOKING</category>
  <category path="">COOKING</category>
```

and reduce this further to include only distinct values:

```
  <category path="">ANTIQUES</category>
  <category path="">COOKING</category>
```

Now we finally have a decent starting point, where we can can apply a template to each such category to do:

```
<xsl:template match="category">
    <node name="{.}" id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$child-categories"/>
    </node>
</xsl:template>
```

where `$child-categories` stands for an expression selecting the categories whose @path attribute matches the concatenation of the current @path and the current value.

I am using the full path to each category, in order to prevent false positive matches in case category names are not unique across branches.

---

As a proof-of-concept, I have written the following stylesheet that utilizes some EXSLT extension functions, namely: exsl:node-set(), str:tokenize() and set:distinct():

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl set str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- first-pass -->
<xsl:variable name="categories">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Subjects/subject">
        <xsl:variable name="steps" select="str:tokenize(literal, ' / ')" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$steps" >
            <category>
                <xsl:attribute name="path">
                    <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::token" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '/')" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </category>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="category-set" select="exsl:node-set($categories)/category" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- output-->
    <nodes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="set:distinct($category-set[not(string(@path))])"/>
    </nodes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category">
    <node name="{.}" id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="set:distinct($category-set[@path=concat(current()/@path, current(), '/')])"/>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running on a processor that supports all of these extension functions (libxslt), the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
  <node name="ANTIQUES" id="idp4576">
    <node name="Americana" id="idp4704"/>
    <node name="Art" id="idp327680"/>
  </node>
  <node name="COOKING" id="idp25520">
    <node name="Beverages" id="idp25648">
      <node name="General" id="idp400976"/>
      <node name="Bartending" id="idp27984"/>
    </node>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I can only use XSLT 1.0 so couldnt use your suggested solution. However, I followed the logic the code it in java and it worked like a charm. thanks :)